# creating a folder with wrong format

Tags: c#, directory

I've encountered the weirdest thing, when creating a folder with a wrong format like "$/folder" it's being created and from that point on it's there.

can someone explain to me where it's being created?

the following code illustrates it:

```
public DirectoryInfo CheckIfFolderExistAndIfNotCreateIt(string path)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            return Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        return null;
    }

    [Test]
    public void CheckIfFolderExistAndIfNotCreateIt_NotExistPathWithDollarSign_ReturnNull()
    {
        var directoryInfo = CheckIfFolderExistAndIfNotCreateIt("$/Folder/");
        Assert.IsNull(directoryInfo);
    }
```

Comment: It should create a directory called "$" in your working directory and then a "Folder" directory under that.  Just check out the `directoryInfo.FullName` to see the entire path.

Comment: you're right! thanks!!!

Comment: I assume you though "$" wasn't a valid directory character.  If you want to know what the invalid directory characters are you can get them from `Path.GetInvalidPathChars()`